# ireport crosstab with generic column group?

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

I have a problem with *JasperReports* crosstab report.

For example, I have data that currently is in this format:

```
| Date      | salesman      | area      | outlet    |
-----------------------------------------------------
| Date A    | Salesman A    | Area A    | Outlet A  |
| Date A    | Salesman A    | Area A    | Outlet B  |
| Date A    | Salesman A    | Area A    | Outlet C  |
| Date B    | Salesman B    | Area A    | Outlet A  |
| Date B    | Salesman B    | Area A    | Outlet D  |
```

I need to output the data in this format:

```
Date    | Salesman      | Area      | Outlet 1 | Outlet 2 | Outlet 3 | etc
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Date A  | Salesman A    | Area A    | Outlet A | Outlet B | Outlet C | ...
Date B  | Salesman B    | Area A    | Outlet A | Outlet D | .......  | ...
```

When creating a crosstab, i do a simple query `SELECT * FROM table`
and then on crosstab wizard, i have set date as row group.

What should i set in column group?

[image: Crosstab column group]

I need to set the column group as outlet counter, not the outlet value? and measure value is outlet.

How to do this in iReport?

previously, i've thinking about using postgreSQL crosstab query.

something like:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstabN(
    'SELECT salesman::text, date::date AS visit_date, outlet::text
    FROM table'
)
```

The output for above is in this format:

```
salesman      | category_1     | category_2     | category_3
------------------------------------------------------------
Salesman A    | Outlet A       | Outlet B       |
Salesman B    | Outlet A       | Outlet C       |
```

but i'm stuck on implement the query with *JasperReports*.

The output report should be the same like postgreSQL crosstab query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a cross tab

```
salesman      | category_1     | category_2     | category_3
------------------------------------------------------------
Salesman A    | Outlet A       | Outlet B       |
Salesman B    | Outlet A       | Outlet C       |
```

Your data selection should be

```
salesman   |  category    |   value
-------------------------------------
Salesman A |  category_1  | Outlet A
Salesman B |  category_1  | Outlet A
Salesman A |  category_2  | Outlet B
Salesman B |  category_2  | Outlet C
```

The `rowGroup` will have bucket expression

```
<bucket class="java.lang.String">
    <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{salesman}]]></bucketExpression>
</bucket>
```

and the `columnGroup` will have

```
<bucket class="java.lang.String">
    <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{category}]]></bucketExpression>
</bucket>
```

Hence you should not try to get crosstab structure from database but flat structure where the name of the crosstab column is one column of your result.

Comment: yes, I know I have to produce data like that, but i didn't know how to get category count within its partition (category_N, category_N, etc)
i just found out the postgreSQL [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html), i use the `row_number` function to get number of the current row within its partition. Thanks for your answer.