# How to reference collection fields from XML data source in Jasper?

Tags: xml, xpath, collections, jasper-reports

I have been asked to modify a template with an XML data source in Jasper to use dynamic columns from a Java program. Therefore, I have gathered all the columns that should be displayed in the PDF in a list, which should then be printed in out in the PDF as the columns of a table. Since I am a beginner in Jasper and ran into the problem of my list being null inside the subreport, I thought it might be easier to start by showing an element of the list in the main report first and continue from there on.

However, it seems like the list is always is null even in the main report, and I have tried various different approaches to try to print out the content of the list. I first checked that the actual content of the list is not null, and that could be verified in the generated XML. Then in Jasper I tried to create a list field in the main report pointing to the variable in my java program (which works just fine for other variables, strings for example). Making the field to only access one field in the list, or printing out the whole list both result in a null value being printed in the generated PDF.

So it seems like I must have misunderstood how to reference/access lists when dealing with XML as a data source in Jasper.

This is how the list looks like in the XML:

```
<kunde>102591</kunde>
<company>Sony</company>
<currentDate>16.02.2019</currentDate>
<columns>
    <string>id</string>
    <string>type</string>
    <string>name</string>
    <string>area</string>
    <string>salary</string>
</columns>
```

I added the field in the main report like this: 
[image: The added field in the main report]

Non-collections, for example strings work just fine: 
[image]

Do I need to reference the collection field in a different way than normal string fields for example? If anyone could explain what is the problem here, that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can references like that, it will not be automatically converted to java.util.List, but you can create a subdatsource on your columns tag. Also watch out making dynamic columns in jasper report is so simple you will need to use a crosstab

Comment: Hi Petter, could you go into some more detail on what you mean here? I have tried making a subdatasource pointing to my list in my Java-class, however the problem persists. Once I can print out the contents of my column-list I will continue with the crosstab, but for now I am stuck with this issue of printing this list. Any ideas? And how would I create this subdatasource exactly? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, I pushed an answer on how you can reference the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jasper reports will not convert your nodes automatically to a `java.util.List` since it would not know how to do this.

**Instead**, you can create another datasource using for example [`subDatasource`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRXmlDataSource.html#subDataSource-java.lang.String-), and then use this datasource to iterate the values/collection.

Note: It's not simple to make dynamic columns, you will probably need to use a crosstab. In this example I will only show how to output the field values in a columnHeader manner using horizontal print order on a `jr:list`, which will answer the question how to reference collection fields.

## Example

**xml**

```
<records>
    <record>
        <kunde>102591</kunde>
        <company>Sony</company>
        <currentDate>16.02.2019</currentDate>
        <columns>
            <string>id</string>
            <string>type</string>
            <string>name</string>
            <string>area</string>
            <string>salary</string>
        </columns>
    </record>   
</records>
```

**jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_1" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isFloatColumnFooter="true" uuid="b98a8766-0e9e-4ae0-9d7c-509e658cd367">
    <subDataset name="customer" uuid="1b55ccc5-c764-45cf-b5c6-b2dea09c1e32">
        <queryString language="XPath">
            <![CDATA[/records/record/columns/string]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="string" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[child::text()]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="XPath">
        <![CDATA[/records/record]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="kunde" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[kunde]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="company" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[company]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="currentDate" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[currentDate]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="32" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="4b8856ca-e4f4-4e50-9882-c8c1f9f2fe9c"/>
                <text><![CDATA[kunde]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="8b6f2e55-f3fe-4461-89bd-4e3ba1b5b06b"/>
                <text><![CDATA[company]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="6320c458-dad4-46e8-a229-bbec8902ad73"/>
                <text><![CDATA[currentDate]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="134" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="bde9ccfc-384e-48c7-aafa-3375b4a5d160"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{kunde}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="43d2ce05-e723-4701-96f0-fbdd13768500"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{company}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="298f066d-ce3a-491e-954c-b9d590fabb8f"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{currentDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="43" width="550" height="30" uuid="bfaa5273-3cd6-4538-b95b-fcd356a24423"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Horizontal">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="customer" uuid="3cfd00e4-8793-456e-806f-4ba30e10e6b3">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("/record/columns/string")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="30" width="80">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="bc599749-6639-41d8-abdb-58df6b54f82e"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{string}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**Output**

[image: result]

Comment: Tack så mycket Petter! That really helped me out.

Comment: @Jssson Svensk?, varsågod :), Have fun!

Comment: Jajjemen, en svensk som jobbar i Madrid :) Har kikat lite på info kring crosstabs, men verkar lite klurigt helt ärligt... Men det löser sig säkert :)

Comment: @Jssson Du i Spanien och jag i Italien, vi flyr till vàrmen :). Crosstabs is a bit difficult, specially in your case, since you need the datasource to be organized in a certain way. Probably it's best if you do all development in java (also parsing the xml), create a JRBeanCollectionDatasource that you can order and setup to generate crosstabs, then pass that to jasper reports.

Comment: @Jssson checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36263610/5292302) to understand how you need to organize the data to make a crosstab work.